# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `gold'

Tags: color, undefined

When I compile this document using `pdflatex`, my chapter's (and sections and subsections, too) titles are, respectively, blue (here defined as 'azzurro') and gold.

I would like that all titles and subtitles be black.

This is the document:

```
    \documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}

    %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{eurosym}
    \usepackage{makeidx}                % allows index generation
    \usepackage{graphicx}               % standard LaTeX graphics tool
    \usepackage{xtab}                   % when including figure files
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{qtree}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
     \usepackage{psfig}                  % used for the two-column index
     \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}       % places footnotes at page bottom
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{my_listings}
    \usepackage[hyphens]{url}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{float}
     \usepackage{titlesec}
      \usepackage{csquotes}
       \usepackage{python}
      \usepackage{verbatim}
      \usepackage{eurosym}
      \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
     \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
  {\Large\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{azzurro}{\thesection}}{-1.1em}{\hspace{2em}\color{azzurro}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]%
  {\large\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{gold}{\thesubsection}}{-1em}{\hspace{3em}\color{gold}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]%
  {\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{gold}{\thesubsubsection}}{-1em}{\color{gold}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{0.64,0.54,0.29}
\definecolor{azzurro}{rgb}{0,0.29,0.57}

\def\lstlistlistingname{\textbf{Elenco dei listati}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textbf{Indice}}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textbf{Elenco delle figure}}}


\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{gold}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textwidth}{12.7cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3.50cm}
\setlength {\evensidemargin}{-0.3cm}
\setlength {\topmargin}{-1cm}


\makeindex

\author{}

\date{13 marzo 2018}

\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{{\color{azzurro}Roman}}
%\include{frontespizio/frontespizio}
%\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
%\include{dedica/dedica}
%\tableofcontents \listoffigures
%\lstlistoflistings

\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}

%\include{Introduzione/introduzione}
\include{01-IlCrowdsourcing/capitolo-01}
%\include{02-LaSentimentAnalysis/capitolo-02}
%\include{03-ProgettazioneDeiTaskDiBase/capitolo-03}
%\include{04-ImplementazioneDeiTaskDiBaseERisultati/capitolo-04}
%\include{05-ProgettazioneDeiTaskAvanzati/capitolo-05}
%\include{06-ImplementazioneDeiTaskAvanzatiERisultati/capitolo-06}
%\include{07-ConfrontoConApprocciCorrelati/capitolo-07}
%\include{08-DiscussioneInMeritoAll'attivitàSvolta/capitolo-08}

\nocite{*}
%\bibliography{Bibliografia/biblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\include{Ringraziamenti/ringraziamenti}
\end{document}
```

In this way the file is compiled like the attached image.

[image]

When I replace the colors with 'black' as

```
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
```

it give me these errors:

> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color gold
>
> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color azzurro

What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that you are using `\color{azzurro}` (twice: one for counter and other for title) in the definition of `\subsection`.

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
  {\Large\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{azzurro}{\thesection}}{-1.1em}{\hspace{2em}\color{azzurro}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother
```

So just replace `azurro` by `black` or even better delete `\color{azzurro}`, since `black` is the default color.

Do the same in the definition of `\subsection`.

A **bad but faster** solution would be to keep the definitions and just change RGB values to the color named`azurro`, ie, `\definecolor{azzurro}{rgb}{0,0,0}`. With that you will get a *black `azurro`*.

Finally, the error `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color gold` you got was because you had changed the name of the defined color (`gold` by `black`) but you were still using the `gold` color in codes above. This is why *undefined color* error.